# Flutter : unable to reuse views in appdrawer

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

File:homepage.dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
var _scaffoldBody;
var _scaffoldTitle;

@override
initState() {
    _scaffoldTitle=new Text("Wall");
    _scaffoldBody=new Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

    drawer: new Drawer(
      child: ListView(

        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Home'),
            onTap: () {

              setState(() {
                _scaffoldTitle=new Text("Home");
                _scaffoldBody=new Text("Home Page");
              });

              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('MenuItem1'),
            onTap: () {

              setState(() {
                _scaffoldTitle=new Text("1st Menu");
                _scaffoldBody=new TestPage("Page 1");
              });

              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('MenuItem2'),
            onTap: () {

              setState(() {
                _scaffoldTitle=new Text("2nd Item");
                _scaffoldBody=new TestPage("Page 2");
              });

              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    appBar: new AppBar(

      title: _scaffoldTitle,
      elevation: 2.0,
      actions: <Widget>[
      ],
    ),
    body:_scaffoldBody,

);
```

}

file: TestPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget{
  final String rollNumber;
  TestPage(this.rollNumber);

  @override
  TestPageState createState() => new TestPageState(rollNumber);

}
class TestPageState extends State<TestPage>{
  String rollNumber;
  TestPageState(this.rollNumber);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new  Text(rollNumber);
  }

}
```

Output:

- When I chose : "Home" from drawer it shows "Home Page"
- Then I chose : "MenuItem1" it showed "Page 1"
- Then I chose : "MenuItem2" it showed same "Page 1" (unexpected)
- Then I chose : "Home" it showed "Home Page"
- Then I chose : "MenuItem2" it showed correctly as "Page 2"
- Then I chose : "MenuItem1" it showed "Page 2" (unexpected)

unable to solve this.Stuck!! Any solutions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Update your TestPart.dart as follow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget{
  final String rollNumber;
  TestPage(this.rollNumber);

  @override
  TestPageState createState() => new TestPageState();

}
class TestPageState extends State<TestPage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new  Text(widget.rollNumber);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But why? And unfortunately it dint solve another similar use case where I had to populate the app drawer dynamically and onTap() is the StudentPage class which has some complex views with firebase data.

Comment: Yup I ve added!! @anmol.majhail

Answer (score 0):

My StudentPage Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'calendar_utils.dart';
import 'dart:async';
final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
class StudentPage extends StatefulWidget{
  final String rollNumber;
  StudentPage(this.rollNumber);

  @override
  StudentPageState createState() => new StudentPageState(rollNumber);

}
class StudentPageState extends State<StudentPage>{
  final String currentRoll,currentYear="2018-19";
  StudentPageState(this.currentRoll);


  List<String> academicMonth=["June","July","August","September","October","November","December",
                              "January","February","March","April","May"];





  int firstHalfYear=2018,secondHalfYear=2019;

  List<Widget> _monthListArray=[new ListTile(title:new Text("Academic Year",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),),)];
  List<Widget> _listView;

  int _no_of_working=0;
  int _no_of_present=0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState


    _listView=[new Center(
      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
    )];
    _loadMonths();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new RefreshIndicator(child: new ListView(

      children: _listView,
    ), onRefresh: _loadMonths);
  }

  Future<Null> _loadMonths() async {


    _listView.clear();
    await mainReference.child("XXXX").child("attendance").child(
        widget.rollNumber).child(currentYear).once().then((
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      try {

        int monthIndex=5;                                             //monthIndex starts from June
        for(var month in academicMonth){
          debugPrint("Month:"+month);
          monthIndex=(monthIndex+1)%12;           //month index cycles throughout 1-12
          if(monthIndex==0) monthIndex=12;
          List<Widget> _daysList=[];
          _monthListArray.add(new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),child: new Text(month+" "+(monthIndex<6?secondHalfYear:firstHalfYear).toString(),style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20.0),),));                       //initializing the month
          _monthListArray.add(new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0,bottom: 10.0),child:
          new Row(children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("S",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("M",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("T",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("W",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("T",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("F",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Center(child: new Text("S",style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
            ),

          ],),));
          debugPrint(monthIndex.toString());
          int freeSpace=CalendarUtils(1,monthIndex,monthIndex<6?secondHalfYear:firstHalfYear).getDayFromDate();
          debugPrint("FreeSpace---"+freeSpace.toString());
          if(freeSpace!=0){

            for (var i = 0; i < freeSpace; i++) {
              _daysList.add(new Text(""));
            }
          }
          debugPrint(monthIndex.toString());
          var year=monthIndex<6?secondHalfYear:firstHalfYear;
          debugPrint("Year"+year.toString());
          debugPrint("Forloop limit:"+CalendarUtils(1,monthIndex,monthIndex<6?firstHalfYear:secondHalfYear).numberOfDays().toString());
          for(var day=1;day<=CalendarUtils(1,monthIndex,monthIndex<6?secondHalfYear:firstHalfYear).numberOfDays();day++){

            try {
              //debugPrint(day.toString()+":"+dataSnapshot.value[month][day].toString());
              if (CalendarUtils(day, monthIndex,
                  monthIndex < 6 ? secondHalfYear: firstHalfYear)
                  .getDayFromDate() != 0){
                if (dataSnapshot.value[month][day].toString() == "1") {
                      _no_of_working++;
                      _no_of_present++;
                      _daysList.add(
                          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0,top: 2.0,bottom: 2.0),
                            child: new Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 30.0,
                              height: 30.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(50.0)),
                                  color: Colors.green),
                              child: new Text(
                                day.toString(),
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      );
                }

                else if (dataSnapshot.value[month][day].toString() == "0"){
                  _no_of_working++;
                  _daysList.add(
                      new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0,top: 2.0,bottom: 2.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: 30.0,
                        height: 30.0,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(50.0)),
                            color: Colors.redAccent),
                        child: new Text(
                          day.toString(),
                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      )
                  );
                }
                else {

                  _daysList.add(
                      new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0,top: 2.0,bottom: 2.0),
                        child: new Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          width: 30.0,
                          height: 30.0,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(50.0)),
                              ),
                          child: new Text(
                            day.toString(),
                            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  );
                }
            }else {
                _daysList.add(
                    new Center(child: new Text(day.toString(), style:
                    new TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),)));
              }
            }catch (e){
              _daysList.add(new Center(child:new Text(day.toString(),style:
              new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ));
            }
          }

            Widget _daysGrid=new GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 7,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              childAspectRatio: 1.5,
            children: _daysList,
          );
          _monthListArray.add(_daysGrid);
        }

      }catch(e){}
      _monthListArray.add(new Text((_no_of_present/_no_of_working).toString()));
    });
    this.setState((){
      _listView=_monthListArray;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the Constructor for StudentPageState its Not required StudentPageState(this.currentRoll);
- Replace currentRoll with widget.rollNumber

Comment: remove String currentRoll; & whereever in Code you are using currentRoll replace it with widget.rollNumber

Comment: What is the Exact issue now .? Error or something.?

Answer (score 0):

My HomePage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smart_school_parent/TestPage.dart';
import 'package:smart_school_parent/attendance.dart';
import 'package:smart_school_parent/post.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:smart_school_parent/auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;
  HomePage({Key key, this.auth, this.onSignOut}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState(this.auth);
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  List<PostData> post_list = new List();


  var _scaffoldBody;
  var _loading;
  var _currentYear;
  var _scaffoldTitle;
  List<Widget> _childrenList=[new Text("Profiles",textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)];

  BaseAuth auth;

  _HomePageState(this.auth);

  @override
  initState() {

    //_children=updateChildren();
    _updateChildren();
    getList();
    _loading=true ;
    _scaffoldTitle=new Text("Wall");
    _scaffoldBody=new Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('XXXXx'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color:Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Wall'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _scaffoldTitle=new Text("Wall");
                    _scaffoldBody=new RefreshIndicator(child: _loadWall(), onRefresh: getList);
                  });

                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
             Column(
               children: _childrenList,
             ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: new AppBar(

          title: _scaffoldTitle,
          elevation: 2.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
        body:_scaffoldBody,

    );

  }

  Future <Null> getList() async {
    await mainReference.child("NISE-Coimbatore").child("posts").once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      this.setState(() {
        post_list.clear();
        if(dataSnapshot.value!=null){
        for (var value in dataSnapshot.value.values) {
          post_list.add(new PostData.fromJson(value));
          //debugPrint(value.toString());
        }
        }else{
          this.setState((){

          });
        }
      });
    });
    setState(() {
      _scaffoldBody=new RefreshIndicator(child: _loadWall(), onRefresh: getList);
    });
  }
  Widget _loadWall(){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return new Post(post_list[index].image,post_list[index].title,post_list[index].content);
        },
          itemCount: post_list == null ? 0 : post_list.length,)
      ],
    );
  }

   _updateChildren() async {
    _currentYear= await mainReference.child("attendance").child("currentYear").once();
    await auth.currentUser().then((String userId) async{

      mainReference.child("NISE-Coimbatore").child("parents").child(userId).child('children').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for (var value in dataSnapshot.value){
          this.setState((){
            _childrenList.add(
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                child:  ListTile(
                  title: Text(value.toString()),
                  onTap: () {

                    super.setState(() {

                      _scaffoldTitle=new Text(value.toString());
                      this._scaffoldBody=new StudentPage(value.toString());

                    });

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),

            );
          });

          //debugPrint("Childrrncount::"+value.toString());
        }
      });
    });
   }



}
class PostData{
  String title;
  String content;
  String image;

  PostData(this.title, this.content, this.image);

  PostData.fromJson(var value) {
    this.title = value['title'];
    this.content = value['content'];
    this.image = value['image'];
  }
}
```

_childrenList has two elements. The datasnapshot.values has [15505,15501] two roll numbers

Both rollnumbers from firebase appear on the drawer box and on tap it is expected to show StudentPage(15501.tostring()) or StudentPage(15505.tostring())

it works as expected if select "Wall" from drawer and then any of the "rollNumbers"

it is not working if i switch from one of the rollNumbers to other rollNumber in the drawer.

Similar to my first post. Only the _scaffoldTitle changes accordingly.

Comment: Ok so what i get is first time if you select any roll number page load is working, but if you select wall then roll number page its doesn't work .?

Comment: the dynamically created drawer items are as follows 1.Wall 2.15501 3.15505. When I switch from wall to any of the rollnumbers its working. But when is switch from any of the roll number to other rollnumber then it is not working. For eg. if switch from 15501 to 15504 in drawer only the appbar title changes not the body. It shows 15501's body

Comment: Ok, trying removing keyword this & super while calling setState()  & this._scaffoldBody to normal _scaffoldBody

Comment: Also call_updateChildren();  after the first frame is loaded - add this in initState(): 
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _updateChildren();
    });

Comment: No it dint help

Comment: I had an workaround which is not a best practice. The Problem is I cant reuse the same class. So I had to create different Classes( with same content but different name) like (StudentPage1,StudentPage2) and call them it worked. I dont know what is the problem still. I will try to raise a complete issue in github

Comment: Best approach here would be to use Navigator and push from home page to student page. You won't need scaffold body variable that way. You can push title and roll number both